# Need help merging results from 3 columns into 1 (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm pretty new to SQL and am having trouble figuring out how to combine 3 columns into 1 to simplify a report I'm creating. The columns use CASE statements. Based on my research I believe I need to use UNION or UNION ALL but nothing I've tried has worked.

Here is the code. I omitted several columns and just left the 3 columns in question for brevity.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN r.scode IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE r.scode
    END 'Column 1',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT DISTINCT u.scode
            FROM Unit
            WHERE c.itype = 4) IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE u.scode
    END 'Column 2',
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT DISTINCT f.scode
            FROM UnitType
            WHERE c.itype = 10) IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE f.scode
    END 'Column 3'
FROM CapsConfig c
INNER JOIN CapsXref x
    ON c.hmy = x.hcapsconfig
INNER JOIN Prop p
    ON c.hprop = p.hmy
LEFT OUTER JOIN ChgTyp t
    ON x.hchgcode = t.hmy
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tenant r
    ON c.hpointer = r.hmyperson
LEFT OUTER JOIN Unit u
    ON c.hpointer = u.hmy
LEFT OUTER JOIN UnitType f
    ON c.hpointer = f.hmy;
```

The current output is:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3

                        0021117U
                        0021117U
                        0021117U
                        0032117U
                        0032117U
                        0032117U
            16NL1
            16NL1
            16NL1
            102FL1
            102FL1
            102FL1
t0002177
t0002178
t0002178
t0002178
```

I would like it to be:

```
Combined

0021117U
0021117U
0021117U
0032117U
0032117U
0032117U
16NL1
16NL1
16NL1
102FL1
102FL1
102FL1
t0002177
t0002178
t0002178
t0002178
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: To me, it looks like you want `scode` to be a single column. So, your hierarchy would be `Tenant, Unit, UnitType`. I would use `ISNULL()` function, but put the `c.itype` with an `AND` on the `LEFT JOIN`. If I'm on the right track, let me know and I'll put this in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN r.scode IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE r.scode
    END 'Column 1',
    CASE 
        WHEN ( u.scode IS NULL AND c.itype = 4)  THEN ''
        ELSE u.scode
    END 'Column 2',
    CASE 
        WHEN ( f.scode IS NULL AND c.itype = 10)  THEN ''
        ELSE f.scode
    END 'Column 3'
FROM CapsConfig c
INNER JOIN CapsXref x
    ON c.hmy = x.hcapsconfig
INNER JOIN Prop p
    ON c.hprop = p.hmy
LEFT OUTER JOIN ChgTyp t
    ON x.hchgcode = t.hmy
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tenant r
    ON c.hpointer = r.hmyperson
LEFT OUTER JOIN Unit u
    ON c.hpointer = u.hmy
LEFT OUTER JOIN UnitType f
    ON c.hpointer = f.hmy;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was making this more complicated than it needed to be. I got the results I wanted with one subquery:

```
(SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN c.itype = 1 THEN r.scode
            WHEN c.itype = 4 THEN u.scode
            WHEN c.itype = 10 THEN f.scode
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
declare @t table (col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50),col3 varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('','','0021117U')
insert into @t values ('','16NL1','')
insert into @t values ('t0002177','','')


select col1 from @t
where col1 <> ''

union all

select col2 from @t
where col2 <> ''

union all

select col3 from @t
where col3 <> ''
order by 1
```